# Comment peut-on traduire "must've been" ?

Tags: grammaire, traduction, anglais

Par exemple, en anglais, quand je ne sais pas exactement la quantité, la taille, la force, etc. de quelque chose, parfois, je pourrais dire "must've *past participle*". Voici des exemples:

1. He must've drank 15 beers last night!
2. I must've read 10 books just this month.
3. I must've been, what, 8 years old at the time?

On le dit aussi quand on veut exprimer que quelque chose est nécessaire pour une autre chose d'avoir arrivé :

1. He must've walked right through the forest to have arrived to fast.
2. Do you think it was Jim who called last night? Must've been [because of something else obvious in the context].
3. I must've been 8 years old at the time, because this happened in 1997.

Pour le premier groupe, je pense que je dirais

> Je crois que [suj.] [subj.]...

Et pour le deuxième,

> Il a fallu que/il fallait que...

Mais je peux pas le justifier avec ce que je sais à mon niveau pour l'instant. Alors, qu'est-ce que vous pensez?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Les premières traductions qui me viennent à l'esprit utilisent le verbe devoir (elles fonctionnent aussi bien pour le premier et le second groupe).

> - Il **a dû** boire 15 bières hier soir !
> - J'**ai dû** lire 10 livres rien que ce mois-ci.
> - Je **devais** avoir, quoi, 8 ans à cette époque ?
> - Il **a dû** marcher à travers la forêt pour arriver aussi vite.
> - Est-ce que tu penses que c'est Jim qui a appelé hier soir ? Ça **doit** être lui.
> - Je devais avoir 8 ans à l'époque, parce que c'était en 1997.

Rajouter un *peut-être* rajoute une dimension d'incertitude (qui existe déjà avec le *dû* seul).

> - Il a **peut-être dû** boire 15 bières hier soir !
> - Il a **peut-être** bu 15 bières hier soir !

*Je crois que* marche plutôt bien aussi. En revanche, *il a fallu que* n'est pas idiomatique et ne marche pas très bien dans ces exemples.

Comment: Would “il a dû marcher à travers la forêt pour arriver aussi vite” not (also?) mean ‘he had to walk through the woods to get there so quickly’ (i.e., _c’était nécessaire pour lui de marcher…_ rather than _sans doute il a marché…_)? I would have guessed at “il doit avoir marché à travers la forêt…” for the meaning expressed by the English phrase. Similarly, “ca doit être lui” sounds more like ‘it ought to be him’ to me than ‘must’ve been’, with less certainty… isn’t it?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The sentence has two different meanings that depend on the context. "Ca doit être lui" is the closest proposition I could find. If you want more certainty, you can say "C'est surement lui".